# list index out of range error for loan data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to recreate this analysis: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/203258_d20c1a34bc094151a0a1e4f4180c5f6f.html

I could not get the shell script to work on my computer so I created a code to essentially do just that:

```
import sys 

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

in_fp = open(input_file,"r")
out_fp = open(output_file,"w")

count = 0 

for line in in_fp:
     if count == 1:  
         out_fp.write(line+"\n")
     elif count>1:
         elems = line.split(",")
         loan = elems[16].upper()
         if loan == "FULLY PAID" or loan == "LATE (31-120 DAYS)" or loan == "DEFAULT" or loan == "CHARGED OFF":
             out_fp.write(line+"\n")
     count+=1
in_fp.close()
out_fp.close()
```

While this code works for the year 2015 data, when I run it for 2012-2013 data I get the error message:

```
File "ShellScript.py", line 16, in <module>
    loan = elems[16].upper()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this error to get the data to sort? Thank you

Comment: I suggest you print elems before assigning the loan, so you can see why the data is shorter than expected

Comment: You are currently skipping the first line (where count is 0) of the file and automatically writing the second line of the file (where count is 1).  Is that because you are preserving headers?  Are the headers really on the second line or is that a bug?

Answer (score 0):

One of your lines doesn't have 17 elements therefore `elems[16]` fails.  This is usually caused by a blank line in your data.  It can also be caused by a quoted field with embedded newlines.  If it's a quoted field with embedded newlines you will need to use the `csv` module.

Here is a rewrite using the csv module.  It reports and skips short lines.  I have changed it to be more Pythonic.

```
import sys
import csv

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]
ncolumns = 17 # IS THIS RIGHT?
keep_loans = {"FULLY PAID", "LATE (31-120 DAYS)", "DEFAULT", "CHARGED OFF"}

# with statment automatically closes files after block
with open(input_file, "rb") as in_fp, open(output_file, "wb") as out_fp:
    reader = csv.reader(in_fp)
    writer = csv.writer(out_fp)
    # you are currently skipping line 0
    next(reader)
    # copy headers
    writer.writerow(next(reader))
    # you are currently adding an extra newline to headers
    # writer.writerow([]) # uncomment if you want that extra newline

    for row_num, row in enumerate(reader, start=2):
        if len(row) < ncolumns:
           # report and skip short rows
           print "row %s shorter than expected. skipping row.  row: %s" % (row_num, row)
           continue
        # use `in` rather than multiple == statements
        if row[16].upper() in keep_loans
             writer.writerow(row)
```